# Can C++ class used in Gradle as it support groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

I  am trying to learn gradle and got to know that you can use Java class into gradle tasks as it is written in groovy but my application is written in C++ then can I use C++ into gradle?

Comment: show us your efforts please.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to build C++ application, you may find this guide handy

https://guides.gradle.org/building-cpp-libraries/

On the other hand if you want to use C++ code from Gradle you need to wrap the code using JNI

https://objectpartners.com/2015/04/21/interfacing-groovy-and-java-with-native-libraries/